# Retrieve Public Facebook Posts with App ID and App Secret

Tags: facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-boot, spring-social-facebook

I have a Facebook app that is associated with a companys page. The page has public posts on it and I would like to retrieve those posts (and eventually images etc) via the spring-social-facebook plugin for spring-boot.

I am able to retrieve the Page object without authenticating as a specific FB user, but how can I get the public information (such as the wall posts, images uploaded etc) associated with the company?

```
    Page page = facebook.pageOperations().getPage("1234567");
    List<Post> posts = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();

    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
    return "hello";
```

I am able to access the [page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/Page.html) object (${page.category}), but when I try to get their posts I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.
```

My goal is to create REST services for this specific company to use to populate a read-only front end with its own public FB data without requiring any end user authentication with Facebook.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Page Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/), to fetch the posts-

> An **app or user access token** is needed to view fields from fully public pages.
>   
> A **user access token** is needed to view fields from *restricted pages* that this person is able to view (such as those restrict to certain demographics like location or age, or those only viewable by Page admins).
>   
> A **page access token** can also be used to view those restricted fields.

To get the posts from a public page without user authentication, you can use the **app access token**(`app_id`|`app_secret`) (expires *never*).

But please note its not safe to expose the app access token to the client side because it is kind of a password to your app.

Comment: I am writing a spring app that will authenticate against FB and return the publicly available data. That app has the app token (generated from the app id and secret) and should be using it to make the Page request (as you noted, in the first line, the app token should be enough to pull back the data). This keeps the id and secret from the public. However, with the code above, I am still seeing the exception I posted.

Comment: I didnt got you, but did you tried that using the app access token?

Comment: I am struggling on how to do exactly that using the spring-social-facebook plugin.

Comment: You can pass access token as a normal parameter in the api call. So just check how to add parameters

Comment: Ok, this works...  curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/15********48/feed?access_token=30***********99|19*************************e0'. I'm thinking that I can write a simple app to proxy these graph requests and append the app_id|app_secret on the server side. I'm still hopeful that I could sort this out in the context of the spring-social-facebook app...

Comment: Ok great, pls mark this as correct if worked. Goof luck

Comment: your answer describes how to interact with the FB API, not how to do so using the spring-social-facebook plugin... Up vote (and much thanks) but it's not the answer to this specific question...

Comment: Do you mean that you need the complete code? Have you got one?